# Get url query parameters in ngrx effects

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am trying to use ngrx router-store module. I have registered a side effect on route change:

```
 @Effect() routeChange$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(routerActions.UPDATE_LOCATION)
    .map(action => {
        if (action.payload.path.indexOf('/applicationList') > -1) {
            return new list.ChangePageAction(new PageInfo(0, 4)); //HOW TO PARSE query params in effects
        } else {
            return {type: 'NOTHING'};
        }
    });
```

Where `ChangePageAction` is COMMAND Action to just indirectly invoke a backend REST search with given `page` and `pageSize` represented by `PageInfo` wrapper.

I need to parse the URL query params: `/applicationList?page=0&pageSize=10` so I can pass them as payload to `ChangePageAction`.

Is there any help from ngrx router-store or do I have to parse manually?

Comment: are you using ngrx-router store?

Comment: Yes I am using ngrx-router, see here also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47202946/angular-router-guard-and-router-navigation-effect-order