# Angular router guard and ROUTER_NAVIGATION effect order

Tags: typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store-4.0

There is a simple (Angular 4) route guard, which waits for some data to be loaded from backend:

```
@Injectable()
export class ContractsLoadedGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private store: Store<State>) { }

    waitForData(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.store.select(state => state.contracts)
            .map(contractList => !!contractList)
            .filter(loaded => loaded)
            .take(1);
    }

    canActivate(): Observable<boolean> { return this.waitForData(); }
}
```

Routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'app-list', canActivate: [ContractsLoadedGuard], component: AppListComponent },
];
```

And finally there is an @ngrx/effects triggered by @ngrx/router-store v4 `ROUTER_NAVIGATION` action:

```
@Effect() routeChange$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(ROUTER_NAVIGATION)
    .filter((action: RouterNavigationAction) => action.payload.routerState.url.indexOf('/app-list') > -1)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store.select(state => state.contracts))
    .switchMap(([action, contracts]: ([RouterNavigationAction, ContractList])) =>
        this.restClient.load(action.payload.routerState.queryParams, contract));
```

Unfortunatelly when navigation changes to `/app-list` the ngrx effect is executed first (before guard) and thus the data `state.contracts` are not available yet. **The guard has not been executed yet.**
I do have to add `.combineLatest()` Rx operator to wait for the `contracts` data in effect also (this is guard's job):

```
@Effect() routeChange$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(ROUTER_NAVIGATION)
    .filter((action: RouterNavigationAction) => action.payload.routerState.url.indexOf('/app-list') > -1)
    .combineLatest(this.contractListGuard.waitForContractsToLoad(), a => a) <- HERE
    .withLatestFrom(this.store.select(state => state.contracts))
    .switchMap(/* same here */)
```

I'm not unsure if this is good solution enough. There must be a better way to do it - not duplicate the guard functionality in effect.

To summarize: On application boostrap, I need to fetch some data from backend - `contracts`. If an user navigates to `/app-list` (immediate redirect) there are other data fetched from server - based on some query params and `contracts` - the ngrx router `ROUTER_NAVIGATION` `effect` execution order is before the guard execution order. How to handle this properly?

Based on [GitHub - state_management_ngrx4](https://github.com/vsavkin/state_management_ngrx4/blob/master/clientapp/src/app/model.ts#L101)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one way to achieve it. You can subscribe to the Angular Router's ResolveEnd event https://angular.io/api/router/ResolveEnd in your effect and then dispatch your own action for RESOLVE_END where you can do stuff with your resolver / guard data.

Actually there is an PR in ngrx/platform that I created where ngrx/router will dispatch NAVIGATE_RESOLVE_END action out of the box. I am waiting for ngrx team to accept my PR. https://github.com/ngrx/platform/pull/524/

You can subscribe to router events and filter it for the Resolve End and dispatch your own action call it Router_Resove_End action etc.

```
this.router.events.filter(e => e instanceof ResolveEnd).subscribe(s => {
 // dispatch your own action here.
});
```

Comment: How can I subscribe to Angular Router's ResolveEnd event in my effect? Can you outline some events flow or add some (pseudo) code to achieve the guard check first? Thanks

Comment: You can subscribe to router events and filter it for the Resolve End and dispatch your own action call it Router_Resove_End action etc.   this.router.events.filter(e => e instanceof ResolveEnd).subscribe(s => {
      // dispatch your own action here.
    });

Comment: > You can subscribe to the Angular Router's ResolveEnd event  in your effect ..

Can you modify the code snippet and add `@Effect()` into the answer, please ?

`@Effect() routeChange$ = this.actions$.ofType(ROUTER_NAVIGATION) ... how to subscribe to resolve end in effect here ...`

Comment: Hi @Felix, I am trying to explain that in your effect class you have to subscribe to the router event by your own. For this you do not need @Effect(). You should not subscribe to ROUTER_NAVIGATION action. Here effect will not help you. The other option is do not subscribe to router_navigation action and from your contractListGuard dispatch an CONTRACT_LIST_LOADED action which you can subscribe in your effect.

Answer (score 0):

There is very nice wrap up on [Medium](https://medium.com/@amcdnl/angular-routing-data-with-ngrx-effects-1cda1bd5e579):

```
@Injectable()
export class RouterEffects {
    constructor(
        private actions$: Actions,private router: Router,private location: Location,private store: Store<any>
    ) {this.listenToRouter();}

    @Effect({ dispatch: false })
    navigate$ = this.actions$.pipe(ofType('[Router] Go')...);
    @Effect({ dispatch: false })
    navigateBack$ = this.actions$.pipe(ofType('[Router] Back'), tap(() => this.location.back()));

    @Effect({ dispatch: false })
    navigateForward$ = this.actions$.pipe(ofType('[Router] Forward'),...);

    private listenToRouter() {
        this.router.events.pipe(
            filter(event => event instanceof ActivationEnd)
        ).subscribe((event: ActivationEnd) =>
            this.store.dispatch(new RouteChange({
                params: { ...event.snapshot.params },
                path: event.snapshot.routeConfig.path
            }))
        );
    }
}
```

and then instead of:

```
@Effect() routeChange$ = this.actions$.ofType(ROUTER_NAVIGATION)
```

use:

```
@Effect() routeChange$ = this.actions$.ofType(ofType('[Router] Route Change'))
```